# ws2801 Power Issues

Tags: led, led-strip

I am (eventually) going to try to an ambilight build.

I have a 5m strip of 5V WS2801 LEDs. I have been using a LeoStick to try to do some programming with them but I can't get past plugging them in to power. I have tried a 5V 3A power supply and a computer PSU @ 5V 20A.

All I get is the a couple of lights lighting up blue(ish), some more faded than others. There is also a gap of a few LEDs between the ones lighting up; though, no pattern as to which ones are on/off.

All of the above results are without the lights being plugged into any data source. It is purely just 5V in and ground.

Have I bought some dodgy lights or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> All of the above results are without the lights being plugged into any data source.

The WS2801 datasheet does not specify an initial state, therefore you should not assume that it will be "fully off"; connect them to a data source and set them to a known output state before writing them off as broken.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. I was trying to program them using a LeoStick but having no luck. I will try with my Raspberry Pi and update my question.